# On iOS, how to avoid selection of parent node's text on long press on a child?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

After looking for a solution to avoid long-press callout action on iOS, I found the following solution that works well:

```css
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
  user-select: none;
  outline: 0;
```

However, the selection still occurs on any parent node! Like if an event was bubbling somehow. And I do not want to block text selection in the parent markup.

I have demonstrated the behaviour [in the following codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-flower-00k4e?file=/src/App.js).

**Can you tell me how to keep the parent `div` selectable as normal, while blocking all selection when a long press occurs on the child?**

[image]

See the above screenshot, after a long tap in the middle of the screen, some text from behind the div gets selected. Ugh.

(*I'm adding `javascript` and `reactjs` tags as my problem exists in a react app, and I suspect the solution might involve touch events manipulation...*)

Comment: This package will emit a 'long-press' event on a touch that lasts a while, maybe you can use it: https://github.com/john-doherty/long-press-event

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, I think that this package simply introduces a custom event, that will not interact with the above behavior?

Comment: I think you'll need to detect the long press, then de-select the selected text. I haven't found a way to completely prevent text selections.

Comment: Ok I understand. Well, if I cannot avoid the selection, I think i'd rather raise the `isOpen` state to the parent and also prohibit selection there, only when `isOpen === true`, or, apply imperatively on the body, which is probably even better...  although those are quite dirty hacks. I'd prefer to be able to stop the selection to happen in the first place.

Comment: My testing suggests that long press will select text from any location on the page, not just the parent element. If you want to prevent text selection, you might have to disable user select on every element that contains text. Ick!